# How to add a consistent margin to each thumbnail grid item without breaking % grid?

Tags: html, css, grid

I've drawn a bit of a blank when creating a thumbnail grid, I want to add add `20px margin` to each grid item in my `3 column grid` making sure the first and last of each row sit flush with the container. Each grid item has a width of `33.33334%` so when I add `margin-right: 20px;` to each then the grid breaks. As I say, I'm drawing a blank on how to do this keeping the grid consistent, each grid item the same width but with a margin after the first and second items?

**CSS**

```
.grid-item {
    flex: 1 0 33.3334%;
    margin-right: 20px;
    &:nth-child(3n+n) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .grid-inner {
        padding: 20px;
    }
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/styler/pen/xzogr

Comment: You already have 20px padding on .grid-inner.  Do you even still need the 20px margin on .grid-item?  Or are you saying you want to get rid of that padding?

Comment: hey yeah i need to have space between each grid item

Answer (score 1):

How about percentage based margins, to keep the numbers perfect?  This has each grid item at 32% (total 96% for 3 of them) and then a 2% margin on the left and right side of the center item.

```
.grid-item {
   flex: 1 0 32%;

   &:nth-child(3n+2) {
     margin:0 2%;
   }

   .grid-inner {
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest and most robust solution would simply be to use a `<table>`.

You could feature this CSS instead:

```
td {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    align-content: center;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

This would simplify the math, and the need for `flex` and `flex-wrap` etc.